# how to clear threadlocal in thread pool in Java 8

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as the thread pool to execute task, but the problem is the thread pool's thread will reuse the ThreadLocal value, how to clear the ThreadLocal in each thread execute complete? This is the code now I am using:

```
package com.sportswin.soa.robot.common;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MapUtils;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Slf4j
public class ThreadLocalAwareThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public ThreadLocalAwareThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
                                      BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        try {
            
            if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(SessionUtil.getThreadLocal())) {
                SessionUtil.getThreadLocal().clear();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("clear error", e);
        } finally {
            super.afterExecute(r, t);
        }
    }
}
```

but it seems not work. I am searching from internet and read some question that still work it out. So how to clear the threadlocal after thread complete?